# Ember.js - Add record to store when using store.query?

Tags: ember.js

How should I update my model to include new records when using store.query? I'm using store.query for pagination.  From what I've read, I can push the record into the store, but can't seem to get this working?

```
    // users/route.js
    ...
    model(params) {
        return this.store.query('user', {
            page: {
                number: params.page,
                size: params.size
            }
        });
    },
    ...

    // users/new/route.js
    ...
    model() {
        return this.store.createRecord('user');
    },

    actions: {

        save() {
            let model = this.controllerFor('users').get('model');
            model.save().then(() => {
                console.log('user saved');
                this.transitionTo('users');
            });
        },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to retrieve the model form users route. 
In your route action you can just do:

```
        this.get('controller.model').save().then(() => {
            console.log('user saved');
            this.transitionTo('users');
        });
```

That will do a POST request, and persist your user.

Comment: Thanks Igor, i have the list of users and the form on the same page, so when i submit the user, i want to see the list update, but with `store.query` this doesn't happen?

Comment: Yeah, query method doesn't reload on changes... You would need to manually refresh the route model in order to display those changes. What you could do in order to accomplish that is to bubble an action up to your users route, and in there do `this.refresh()`

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Can I manually push the new record into the store?  This seems to be a suggested solution, but can't seem to get it working..

Comment: the save() method already pushes the record to the store. If you check your ember inspector, you will see your new record in there as well. The thing is, it still wont update the model, because it was loaded with query method. You could manualy push the user into the query collerction with `this.controllerFor('users').get('model.content').pushObject(user._internalModel)`, but I wouldn't reccomend messing with that. Yous should just do the action bubble refresh imo.